# Question. Why does the Trenberth et al Global Energy Flow chart divide the incoming solar flux of 1370 $\rm W/m^2$ by 4?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Why would you list the incoming solar radiation as 1/4 of its actual value?
This would have the effect of reducing insolation to -40 deg C at the surface. It seems to me Trenberth is in error. The calculation is correct if you are calculation a flat disk where energy could be averaged over the entire surface. However the Earth is not a flat disk and you can not make meaningful conclusions from such an average.

Comment: Kind of depends on just what you want to use the number for, no? The flux you see at your position on the globe isn’t what I see either, but given the perpendicular flux and knowledge of your global position you can get pretty close.

Comment: General tip: No need to write the word "question" in the title of a question.

Answer (score 1):

To Malawby:
ALL radiation hitting the earth is either absorbed or reflected. Regardless of temperature of the source or the earth. What happen in this scenario is that the earth and the greenhouse gases are exchanging energy by radiation with the net effect of 0 W/m2. If the earth was warmer we would have a net effect of >0 W/m2 etc to the greenhouse gases. Even if you are standing by a wall of ice the ice is radiating to you but you are radiating more to the ice so that the net is from you to the ice.
( Background as a developer of IR-camera for 20+ years. )
( sorry for the answer, I am not allowed comment yet )

Comment: Yes that is a great explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Great question!  So the solar constant at the Earth's position is 1370 $W/m^2$.  The Earth, of course, can to a good degree, be modeled as a sphere.  But the cross sectional area presented to the Sun is that of a circle.  The area of a circle is, of course, $\pi R^2$, where R would be the radius of the Earth.  So the total solar radiation captured is:

$$1370*\pi R^2$$

But with the Earth being a sphere, this amount of radiation is spread across the area of the surface of a sphere, which is $4\pi R^2$.  So the fraction of the solar constant captured by the Earth is:

$$\frac{1370*\pi R^2}{4\pi R^2} = 342 W/m^2$$

or 1/4 of 1370 $W/m^2$.

Now at this point you may stop and say "That's odd.  Why do they spread this energy over the full sphere of the Earth, when only half of the sphere is getting shined on by the Sun at any time?  Shouldn't we divide by 2?"  Good question!

Think of it this way.  Even though half of the Earth is receiving radiation and the other half is not, there is really only one point on the Earth where the radiation would be coming perpendicularly down on the side facing the sun.  At other points, the radiation is coming in at some angle.  As you get close to the horizon, a one square mile area on the surface of the Earth, presents a cross sectional area much, much less than that to the incoming solar radiation.   So this begins to sound like a more complicated calculation.

The way out of this conundrum is to realize climate scientists are just trying to understand the **average** solar radiation striking the Earth over a long period of time.  That's why you divide by the full area of the surface.

If you goal is to be able to draw a picture like the below (from [Kiehl and Trenberth, 1997](http://climateknowledge.org/figures/Rood_Climate_Change_AOSS480_Documents/Kiehl_Trenberth_Radiative_Balance_BAMS_1997.pdf)), you have to deal in averages over the Earth's surface.  And that would include the average radiation outgoing from the Earth's surface as well.

[image]

A great website that I can't give enough kudos to for all the things climate science related that it helped explain to me is [The Science of Doom](https://scienceofdoom.com/).  It [explains](https://scienceofdoom.com/2010/02/06/the-earths-energy-budget-part-one/) the question we are talking about here as well.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However the image that you have provided creates more questions that it answers. We do know that the insolation figure of 342 w/m2 is an average over a 24 hour period. Can we then assume that the other figures are also averages over a 24 hour period. 

Also the figure 324 back radiation coming from Greenhouse gasses absorbed by the Earth's surface seems highly unlikely as any radiation from a colder atmosphere would surly be at an radiative frequency that would not be absorbed by a warmer surface.
Would that not defy the basic laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: Hi @Malawby .  So you have basically two questions here which I will address in two separate comments.  The first regarding time period, I think you would have to give the Trenberth paper a closer read than I have to see if that is addressed.  My assumption here is that the solar insolation value of 1370 W/m^2 is a yearly averages since the Earth's absolute position changes slightly over a year, thus changing the full cross sectional area it presents to the Sun.  So if you are starting with a yearly value of solar insolance, then other numbers you calculate would be yearly averages as well.

Comment: @Malawby , with regards to the 324 W/m^2 back radiation and whether that violates any laws of thermodynamics, this is a questions that is asked frequently by folks skeptical of the entire subject of global warming.  I can only tell you that radiation from a colder surface is certainly able to be absorbed by a warmer surface.  The second law of thermodynamics does not prevent this.  It only says that the NET flow of energy proceeds from a warmer surface to a colder surface.  Science of Doom also talks about this:  https://scienceofdoom.com/roadmap/back-radiation/

Comment: Yes that is a great explanation. Thank you